# Two layer conditional queries in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, search, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm somewhat new to Laravel and have been searching through the documentation and haven't found an answer that fits what I need to do.

I'm trying to run a flexible search query on a products database.

So people can search by Name or Sku ect. but don't can leave some fields blank.

So when an input is null i just replace it with "No(field)Entered".

My search query has to first check if the field is null, if it is not, needs to filter by the parameter given.

A quick SQL representation of what I'm doing is this.

```
$results = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select("SELECT TOP 500 * from dbo.SimpleOrderView 
WHERE ('". $name ."' = 'NoNameEntered' OR Name LIKE '%". $name ."%') 
AND ('". $sku ."' = 'NoSkuEntered' OR Sku LIKE '%". $sku ."%') 
AND ('". $description ."' = 'NoDescriptionEntered' OR ShortDescription LIKE '%". $description ."%')");
```

So the query is messy, but works as expected. I'd like to use Eloquent to clean it up and make it perform the way it is supposed to.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $inputs = $request->only('name', 'sku', 'description');
    $query = Class:take(500);

    foreach ($inputs as $key => $value)
    {
      $new_key = ucfirst($key);
      $new_value = "%{$value}%";
      if (empty($input))
          $query->where("No{$new_key}Entered", 'like', $new_value);
      else
          $query->where($new_key, $new_value);
    }

    return $query->get();
}
```

this should do the trick